# Problem with Show in Haskell for printing a List

Tags: haskell, syntax

Hi I'm implementing Lists in Haskell by myself as Homework, but I'm having a problem with Show

```
data List a = Void | Cons a (List a) -- deriving (Show, Eq)

instance (Show a) => Show (List a) where
  show Void = "[]"
  show (Cons a Void) = show a ++ "]"
  show (Cons a b) = show a ++ ", " ++ show b
```

For example if I have

```
l1 = (Cons 1 (Cons 2 (Cons 3 (Cons 4 (Cons 5 Void)))))
```

Instead of printing

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

It prints

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

It doesn't appear the first "["

How can I fix this?

Comment: Which part of your code do you expect to product the first `[`? I don't see a `[` on its own anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a helper function so that you can handle the `"["` and `"]"` characters separately from showing the "interior" of the list (elements separated by commas):

```
instance (Show a) => Show (List a) where
  show l =
    let showInterior Void = ""
        showInterior (Cons a1 Void) = show a1
        showInterior (Cons a1 b1) = show a1 ++ ", " ++ showInterior b1
     in "[" ++ showInterior l ++ "]"
```

Comment: Oh, thanks! I'm new using Haskell, so I didn't about that